# UITableView adds empty rows above and below, still there after setting header and footer to empty views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my view with a navigation bar, I THINK but not sure, that the empty spaces above and below my table are the header and footer.  I've tried all possible options to set them to nothing but they still show up like this:

[image: image 1]

The same gap is at the top below the "Private Messages" nav bar.  When I start to scroll:

[image: image 2]

it takes up the entire view.  Why doesn't it initially take up the entire area?  In the Size Inspector Header and Footer are set to 1.  I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the header and footer.  Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is dark Cocoa magic :)

Add

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
        ... your additional code
    }
    return self;
}
```

to your view controller.

UPDATE: (from [iOS7CourseSlides.pdf](http://courseware.codeschool.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ios7/iOS7CourseSlides.pdf))

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES;
```

is the same as

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
self.contentSubview.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(64, 0, 0, 0);
self.contentSubview.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -64);
```

So you can use the approach you like more.

Comment: Along with what else?  Just adding that didn't work.  Does it make a difference that I'm using storyboards?  Still learning here...

Comment: Are you sure you have added `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;` to right place? (see my update)

Comment: Yeah, exactly as you have it.  I just ran across a post which did self.talbeView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-50, 0, -50, 0); and messing with the variables fixed it!  Any reason why or why not it's good to use contentInset?

Comment: I do not know why `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets`not works for you. For me it does. May be we have missed something important. But you can use `self.talbeView.contentInset` off course. Please read my answer's update.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation and the link.  I will definitely read it!

Comment: You are welcome! And yes, it is very good link to go through iOS7 GUI features.